# How to distinguish lookup and master-detail in APEX

Tags: apex, relationships

Is it possible to check using Apex, is relationship field type of lookup or master-detail? `Schema.DescribeFieldResult.getType()` for both of them returns simply 'REFERENCE'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getRelationshipOrder` will be null for a lookup relationship, but will be 0 or 1 for a master-detail relationship.

Edit: I second-guessed myself, as I was mobile, but I have confirmed that `getRelationshipOrder` is only populated for master-detail relationships, and null otherwise.

Edit2: Some standard "master-detail" relationships also return null, so you may need a "white-list" of known false negatives.

Comment: Note that the result will also be `null` for at least some standard master-detail relationships (OpportunityId on OLI, and QuoteId on QLI are ones I've confirmed)

Comment: @DerekF Good point. I've edited that in.

Comment: @DerekF I've checked that OpportunityId on OLI is a lookup. Can it vary depending on some conditions?

Comment: @MaciejKról OpportunityId is not a lookup. OpportunityLineItems cannot exist without an Opportunity, OLI has no `OwnerId` field (ownership and sharing are determined by the "Master" record), and you can create a rollup summary of OLIs on Opportunity. All of those are hallmarks of an M-D relationship. Though with it being a standard field and Salesforce being, well... Salesforce, I wouldn't be surprised if they broke their own rules/conventions.

Comment: Salesforce being salesforce, that explains a lot :) thanks for your detailed explanations

Comment: @sfdcfox You said it can be 0 or 1 for M-D, is there any meaning attached to these values as well?

Comment: @Elijah See [CustomObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customfield.htm): 0 is the primary parent, 1 is the secondary parent. If there is only one M-D relationship, that relationship must be set to 0. All lookup fields must not specify a value (it must be null).